# Is Dropbox syncing sufficient protection against ransomware?

Tags: dropbox, malware

To be clear from the start, I'm not referring to stealing things like credit card numbers-- Only "pay us to decrypt your data."  I know that I should encrypt files to protect information from actually being stolen.

Anyway, to the main point.  I've never encountered ransomware before, but I thought I'd better ask people who know better than me to be sure that this is safe.

I have a paid Dropbox account that I use to sync all of my personal files.  My thinking regarding ransomware is that if I do get an infection, I can revert my Dropbox account to the latest pre-infection period.  (And wipe my hard drive(s) to remove the initial infection, of course.)

Is this good thinking, or should I be taking additional measures?

Thanks!

Comment: Additional measures.  This approach is fairly easy to circumvent - you encrypt the files, but keep them transparently accessible. The act of changing them will trigger an upload to dropbox, Then once 30 days passes, turn on the lock.  The original document will be gone from basic dropbox accounts.

Comment: Its's best to have both off-site (DropBox) and on-site (e.g. external HDD or flash drive) backup... belt and suspenders. If ransomware (or physical damage, as from a fire or flood) destroys one of the backups, the other is there. Perhaps alternate backups as frequently as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows Backup & Restore, you should run it to make point in time restore of *folders* and files. Dropbox is not a backup solution. It can restore files, but to restore entire folders and renamed encrypted files (via ransomware) is an arduous task.